# Performance Request PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm focused on a big problem on my web aplication that uses PHP, Ajax and MySql.
I´ve already developed a script that uses a date-range timepicker for make calendars for each store that i have on my database + the advertisement that will be shown on the place. For each advertisement it will be printed 1 more calendar and in each calendar we have an input to write how many times this advertisement will be shown on that day-input.

When the user choose a daterange on year-to-year with 31 places and 1 advertisement for each place, it will be more than 11000 lines on my foreach, which causes a browser stack, and my database will not be updated.

What can i do to perform this type of foreach script?
Thanks!

Comment: is this a php pr a javascript problem you are having?

Comment: Are you sending each request as it's own ajax request? Or are you sending all 11,000 as a single array?

Comment: @Pitchinnate i'm sending over all, because i must have one single "save" button... is that another way to slice the array ?

Comment: @Ibu the problem is with php

Comment: @Amal Murali any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sending it via ajax or with a simple form submit? GET or POST?

Comment: i´m sending via ajax $fn

Comment: So they are actually selecting 11,000 checkboxes or something? Or are they just selecting a start date and end date?

Comment: each input value from the calendar table are pushed to the array.

Comment: Without any code to show what you are actually doing, it would be hard to offer recommendations.  It does however sound like you need to look at restructuring the way you represent your data.

Comment: Steal the idea from this app -> http://www.corntab.com/pages/crontab-gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend having someone selecting 11,000 items at a time. If they were to have something go wrong and start over they would be quite unhappy. Maybe do 3 months at a time or something like that.

The other option if you have to keep it this way is to create arrays for each month maybe and once you are done with a month convert it to a json array so it is one string instead of over 900 individual elements in an array. So when you post you are posting 12 json arrays.

Without showing any code or seeing an example it is a little hard to help.

Comment: thks @Pitchinnate, i will test something like that